# Visual Studio : Unresolved external symbols after adding new DLL APIs

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker

In a Visual Studio 2010 solution, I have 2 projects:

- Project `A` which is a dll project
- Project `B` which is an executable project and depends on project `A` (configured through the solution project dependencies properties)

When I add new APIs in project `A` declared with `__declspec(dllexport)` specified and call them from project `B`.

If I simply "**Build**" the project `B`, it turns out that project `A` is built then project `B` but the linker does not find the new APIs and report them as unresolved external symbols.
Now if I "**Rebuild**" the project `B`, the solution is fully rebuilt and I do not have unresolved symbol linker errors.

Any idea what could cause the builder to not find the new symbols using a simple **Build** action and how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Pretty hard to explain this with the info you provided.  It clearly strongly suggests a build order problem, even though you documented that A gets built first.

You *may* have a problem with the parallel build feature available in VS.  If it doesn't see any dependency between projects then it allows projects to build concurrently, taking advantage of your machine having multiple cpu cores.  You can see A starting building but B starts building right away as well.  Indicated with a numbered messages in the Output window, preceded with 1> and 2>.

If there actually is a dependency then it becomes a race.  If B progresses to the link stage before A is done linking then it will certainly have trouble.  But that is typically announced by it complaining it cannot find the import library for the DLL project.  It finding an old version of A.lib that is missing some identifiers would be an unusual corner case.  Things do however get interesting when it finds A.lib while it is being written.  Which *does* explain what you observed.

Best thing to do is to ensure that VS knows there is a dependency without relying on it figuring it out by itself.  It is not very good at figuring this out for C or C++ projects.  Right-click your B project in the Solution explorer window and click "Project dependencies".  Tick the A project.  Now it will no longer build concurrently, B won't start building until A is done.  Which is essentially what you did by hand to work around the problem.

If you still have trouble then you'll need to suspect other programs on your machine, the kind that mess with files.  Anti-malware software is always on the top of the list of troublemakers like that.  Avast is especially notorious for giving VS a hard time.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I also though about a parallel build issue, but it is not. Project B effectively starts building after project A finishes and there is the corresponding dependencies ticked in the project dependencies view. So I also suspect something more obvious, some kind of file system caching issues. The whole project and output directories are located on a file server. Do you know of any workaround in this area?

Comment: I tried to address this possibility in the last paragraph.  You are adding extra failure modes by building to a separate file server instead of the local disk.  Hard to give specific advice on how to troubleshoot that, anything is possible.  But certainly isn't common.  If you had documented these essential details in your question then I wouldn't have posted this answer btw.  Be sure to include them so I can delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question does it happens every time? It should not. Build command links, create binaries, find resources depending on the existing resource. No, if you change any resource like library, images form designs etc. Then you need to `rebuild (clean+build)`.

To make a project build before another project build. You have to add dependency by this:

1. Right click to solution>properties.
2. Go to Project Dependencies > Select the project and tick the dependent project.
3. Finally right click to your project B select `Set as StartUp Project`.

This will force your project to build sequentially.